# Poisson structure on the linear recursive sequences

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

My main field is $\mathbb C$. One can define a Poisson structure on a variety of the linear recursive sequences using the following formula:
$$\{e_i, e_j\}=(i-j)e_{i+j}$$
where $e_i$ is the function on this variety which provides the $i$th coefficient of a sequence (essentially this is an embedding of this variety into the coadjoint representation of the first Witt algebra).

My questions are:

1) Whether or not this Poisson structure has a special name?

2) Whether or not the symplectic leaves of this Poisson structure are known?